# How to access or recover a defective harddrive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

My ex hdd appears neither in windows explorer nor in CMD. I tried with another computer ...it appears in windows explorer as a local disk and asked me to format it but formatting didnt work, it was prevented.

In CMD it prevents me to order list disk at "diskpart" by preventing 
"DISKPART" from appearing ..but if disconnect it ane reconnect it again "DISKPART" appears but everything is slow .

When I write"select disk (no)" it becomes very slow .Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases i typically start with trying to do hardware diagnostic. 
There is a selection of tools on the UBCD: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ (i am not affiliated with UBCD).

In earlier times we also changed the electronics board of the harddrive to another one of the same model and in 10 of the 100 cases i tried it, this was a success.

Anyway, if you get hold of the data on the disk, i recommend to immediately copy it to another drive and throw the one in question to garbage.

Also it is always worth a try to boot into a live-linux, as they have completely different drivers they behave different than windows regarding error management. Knoppix was the linux i used for this.